# What do I do with my husband?

Tags: behavior

I dont know how to say this but, well, I dont even know if I am asking this on the right website but, I am Jessica and I am 27 years old, and i got a son, Carl. He is only 6 years old and he is very innocent, but his father is teaching him how to use a gun! I dont even know how my husband has that gun but i love Carl and i cant let he know those things!! Well, my husband is aggressive, he already punched me and throwed me on the wall. Of course I ''fought'' back but he is too strong. He has been using drugs lately, that is an absurd! I try to protect my child but hell, I even went to the police to make an occurrence but they said they would do something about it but they DIDNT!!! Im desesperated please I love my son so much and i have this growing hatred in me that wants to kill my husband but I still love him! What should I do??

Comment: Welcome to the community Jessica.  If in the United States, I suggest you try 1-800-799-7233 for help with what the next step is.  The number is for the national domestic violence hotline and offers anonymous support 24/7.  You are in a situation dangerous for both you and your son and need help we cannot offer on this website, but my heart goes out to you.

Comment: Jessica, you need to get your son and yourself out of that situation. Teaching your son how to use a gun is secondary to the fact that your husband is abusive. I strongly suggest you check your area for woman's shelters or places that offer support for victims of domestic abuse, and *get out of there*. This website cannot provide you the information and help that you need, but I sincerely hope that you are able to find it.